# How to prevent non-alphanumeric input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
$("#user").keyup(function(e){ 
    var regx = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
    if (!regx.test('#user')) 
    {$("#infoUser").html("Alphanumeric only allowed !");}
);}
```

`#user` is a text input, and  I want to diplay a warning if user enters anything except letters and numbers.
In the above case, the warning is present whatever is typed.

Comment: with e.g. http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Comment: You're testing your regex on the string `#user` itself, not of the content/value of the element that have the id `user`. `!regx.test($(e).val())` should suit your needs.

Comment: Not an answer, but just a reminder: Don't depend on this if you're submitting values into a database. Javascript can easily be disabled.

Comment: @andy, thanks. I have similar check on php side. I just want to diplay this warning before submitting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

change:

```
if (!regx.test('#user'))
```

to

```
if (!regx.test( $(this).val() ) )
```

Do:

```
$("#user").keyup(function(e){     
    var str = $.trim( $(this).val() );
    if( str != "" ) {
      var regx = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
      if (!regx.test(str)) {
        $("#infoUser").html("Alphanumeric only allowed !");
      }
    }
    else {
       //empty value -- do something here
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04qbyk42/) example

Comment: Thanks to everyOne. It works. But, if the input is empty - warning is also displayed !

Answer (score 4):

You must test with #user element value not '#user' string

```
$("#user").keyup(function(e){ 
    var regx = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
    if (!regx.test($('#user').val()))  // .
    {$("#infoUser").html("Alphanumeric only allowed !");}
);}
```

Answer (score 2):

THis line

```
regx.test('#user')
```

has you testing the string `#user`, and that is a string that has a bad character (the `#`). So it will always say not allowed.

Use the actual value of your `$("#user")` there by using `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#alpha').bind('keypress', function (event) {
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z\b]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
});

$('#numeric').bind('keypress', function (event) {
var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9\b]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
});

$('#alphanumeric').bind('keypress', function (event) {
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\b]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
});


$('#alphanumericspecial').bind('keypress', function (event) {
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 .]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}
});
```

Comment: A short summary would help reviewers (like me) to judge the validity of your answer; interested users wouldn't have to dive into the code to understand your approach. Just a sentence or two would be fine and not too much work.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function isNotAlphanumeric(){
        return (! val.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/))
        //return val.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) ? false : true;
   }
```

so if val is alpha numeric it return false. So based on returned value take appropriate action. You can call this method on key up event.

Comment: `return (! val.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/))` would be a bit cleaner